# SQL JOIN query does not work

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

There are 5 tables involved in this problem:

```
[contact master]
    id (pk)
    title
    fname
    lname
    country

[home address]
    id (pk)
    contact_id (fk)
    hmcountry
    ...

[office address]
    id (pk)
    contact_id (fk)
    off_country
    ...

[category master]
    id (pk)
    name

[category to contacts]
    id (pk)
    catid
    contactid
```

[the following query returns 0 rows]

```
select 
      c1.id, 
      title, 
      fname, 
      lname, 
      c1.country as country, 
      c4.hmcountry as hmcountry, 
      c5.off_country as off_country 
   from 
      contacts
         join contact_to_categories c2 on c2.contactid=c1.id
         join `contact_address` c4 ON c4.`contact_id` = c1.`id` 
         join `contact_offices` c5 ON c5.`contact_id` = c1.`id`
   where 
          c2.catid=2 
      and ( c1.country like '%Korea, North%' 
         or c4.hmcountry like '%Korea, North%' 
         or c5.off_country like '%Korea, North%' )
```

[where as the following works fine and returns intended results]

```
SELECT 
      `contact_id` 
   FROM 
      `contact_address` 
   WHERE 
          `hmcountry` like '%Korea, North%' 
      and `contact_id` in (select `contactid` 
                              from `contact_to_categories` 
                             where `catid` in(2,3,6) )
```

[or even this works too]

```
SELECT 
      `contact_id` 
   FROM 
      `contact_offices` 
   WHERE 
          `off_country` like '%Korea, North%' 
      and `contact_id` in ( select `contactid` 
                               from `contact_to_categories` 
                              where `catid` in(2,3,6) )
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

What I am trying to do is find all contacts which have "Korea, North" as country either in the main contacts master table or in office address or in home address. I have tried with INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN etc but not luck. Please help!

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I notice in your joins you join on contact_id = id but in your working queries you check if contact_id in contactid.  Change your joins to use the same columns that you use in your working query.

To debug, try this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    contacts c1            
WHERE   c1.country LIKE '%Korea, North%'
```

and see what it returns.  Then keep adding a table at a time until you get 0 rows.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    contacts c1            
INNER JOIN contact_to_categories c2 
            ON c2.contactid = c1.id
WHERE   c1.country LIKE '%Korea, North%'
```

Would be next, if that works add on the where clause:

```
c2.catid = 2
```

and so on.

Comment: Just typos. Just wanted to give the idea of the queries I am trying to run. There is no sql error in the query but returns 0 rows.

Comment: @Kunal Okay, you also have catid in(2,3,6) but for the join you have where c2.catid=2.  Is there no rows with id of 2, just 3 and 6?  If there are, follow BClaydon's suggestion to do the joins one at a time to see where you lose your data.

Comment: I tried his suggestion and posted the query also. There are entries with catid=2, but there could be scenarios where I will need to search with multiple Ids so have given as example.

Comment: @Kunal I don't see an edit on your post.  Like he suggested, I would try select * from table1 then just add on the join, then the where for that new join, etc until you run out of rows and pinpoint the statement that isn't working.

Comment: select c1.id, title, fname, lname, c1.country as country, c4.hmcountry as hmcountry, c5.off_country as off_country from contacts c1
join contact_to_categories c2 on c2.contactid=c1.id and c2.catid=2
join `contact_address` c4 on c4.`contact_id` = c1.`id` and c4.hmcountry like '%Korea, South%'
join `contact_offices` c5 on c5.`contact_id` = c1.`id` and c5.off_country like '%Korea, South%'
where c1.country like '%Korea, South%'

Comment: @Kunal Edited my answer with troubleshooting tips.  If that doesn't work give us some sample data in SQL Fiddle we can use to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your WHERE clause is probably filtering out too many values.  Try putting your conditions in the joins.

```
SELECT c1.id
    , title
    , fname
    , lname
    , c1.country AS 'country'
    , c4.hmcountry AS 'hmcountry'
    , c5.off_country AS 'off_country' 

FROM contacts
    JOIN contact_to_categories c2 ON c2.contactid=c1.id
        AND c2.catid = 2
    JOIN `contact_address` c4 ON c4.`contact_id` = c1.`id` 
        AND c4.hmcountry like '%Korea, North%'
    JOIN `contact_offices` c5 ON c5.`contact_id` = c1.`id`
        AND c5.off_country like '%Korea, North%'

WHERE c1.country like '%Korea, North%'
```

In addition, any NULLs can cause rows to drop. I would try left or right joins to see where in the join chain your losing your rows.  Also, break this down and do your joins one at a time.  Start with the base table. Add one join and see if it returns your expected results, then add the next, and so on.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks, will try this shortly and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possibilities here.

The first one is porbably stating the obvious and I doubt this is it, but in your first query you have:

```
WHERE   c2.catid = 2
```

And in your next two queries you have:

```
WHERE `catid` IN (2, 3, 6)
```

Is it possible that all the rows brought back by these two are in CatID 3 and 6? This would explain why your first query returns no results.

The second more likely probability (assuming that your 2nd and 3rd queries still return records if you use `WHERE CatID = 2`) 
is that there are no contacts that have a home address in North Korea and also have an office address, or that have an office address in North Korea and also have a home address.

I am not sure what you tried with LEFT JOINs, but I don't see why this wouldn't return results if both your smaller queries did.

```
SELECT  c1.id, 
        title, 
        fname, 
        lname, 
        c1.country as country, 
        c4.hmcountry as hmcountry, 
        c5.off_country as off_country 
FROM    contacts
        INNER JOIN contact_to_categories c2 
            ON c2.contactid = c1.id
        LEFT JOIN `contact_address` c4 
            ON c4.`contact_id` = c1.`id` 
        LEFT JOIN `contact_offices` c5 
            ON c5.`contact_id` = c1.`id`
WHERE   c2.catid = 2 
AND (   c1.country LIKE '%Korea, North%' 
    OR  c4.hmcountry LIKE '%Korea, North%' 
    OR  c5.off_country LIKE '%Korea, North%' 
    );
```

Comment: The DB already have multiple entries with category Id 2, 3 and 6. There could be cases where I will need to search with multiple categories hence used them in the example.

Comment: Tried the above query. Had to add "FROM contacts c1", other than that it ran ok but taking too long. I waited for 2 minutes and then gave up. Not sure why.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought it would hang for that long, Do you have any indexes on these tables? If so can you update the question with what indexes are in place, and also the EXPLAIN plan for when you run the query that returns no rows.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a pre-query of all distinct contact IDs unioned for any one of the contact, home address or office addresses associated with N. Korea.  From that, join to the contact to categories to filter out your 2, 3, 6 categories.  So now you have a single list of contacts qualified on just their ID.

Now, use that list to join back to the main contacts list on those IDs qualified and join to their respective home or office address locations via LEFT-JOIN in case neither or only one of the two exist.  If an address? great, grab it, otherwise show as blank

```
SELECT
      PQ.Contact_ID,
      cm2.title,
      cm2.fname,
      cm2.lname,
      cm2.country,
      coalesce( ha2.hmcountry, ' ' ) as HomeCountry,
      coalesce( oa2.off_country, ' ' ) as OfficeCountry
   from 
      ( select distinct cm.id as Contact_ID
           from contact_master cm
           where cm.country like '%Korea, North%' 
        union
        select distinct ha.contact_id
           from home_address ha
           where ha.hmcountry like '%Korea, North%' 
        union
        select distinct oa.contact_id
           from office_address oa
           where oa.off_country like '%Korea, North%' ) as PQ

      JOIN contact_to_categories c2c
         on PQ.Contact_ID = c2c.contactid
         AND c2c.catid in(2,3,6)

      JOIN contact_master cm2
         ON PQ.Contact_ID = cm2.id
         LEFT JOIN home_address ha2
            ON PQ.Contact_ID = ha2.Contact_ID
         LEFT JOIN office_address oa2
            ON PQ.Contact_ID = ha2.Contact_ID
```